# How to extract thousands of cells from data frame given row & column numbers?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `col` that I am extracting the cells from. I have vectors of the row and column numbers (`crgbrow` and `crgbcol`, both 2000 long) which I used to try and get the cells.

```
colors = cols[crgbrow, crgbcol]
```

I did this and R gave me a humongous data frame when I just wanted 2000 cell values from cols. How do I solve this? Should I use a for loop to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cbind` so you can access one element at a time.

```
cols[cbind(crgbrow, crgbcol)]
```

Using a reproducible example :

```
cols <- mtcars
crgbrow <- c(2, 4)
crgbcol <- c(1, 5)
```

Here you want to extract 2nd row, 1st column and 4th row 5th column but when you do

```
cols[crgbrow, crgbcol]

#                mpg drat
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0 3.90
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4 3.08
```

You get 2nd row, 1st and 5th column & 4th row, 1st and 5th column. If you `cbind` the vectors you get what you'll expect.

```
cols[cbind(crgbrow, crgbcol)]
#[1] 21.00  3.08
```